# Which tensor power of a given representation contains the trivial one?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, unitary-representations

If $R$ is an irreducible representation of a simple Lie-groups $G$ I assume there is always a lowest integer $n$ such that the tensor product representation $R \otimes R \otimes \ldots \otimes R$ (n times) contains the trivial (or singlet) representation. I can more or less obtain $n$ on a case-by-case basis (for example with $G=SU(N)$ and $R=Fund$ it appears $n=N$) but first of all is there an established name for $n(G,R)$? And is there a generic method to find it for any $G$ and $R$?

Comment: There’s an easy obstruction: Rep(G) is graded by central character, and the trivial character has trivial grading.  So for your example of SU(n) with its standard rep this tells you only powers which are multiples of n can possibly contain the trivial.

Comment: If $R$ is irreducible of highest weight $\lambda$ then the $n$ should be the minimal $n$ such that $n\lambda$ belongs to the root lattice (as opposed to the weight lattice), right?

Comment: @SamHopkins: Not quite, because when $\lambda$ is in the root lattice the answer isn't 1!

Comment: @NoahSnyder: Ahh, sorry, I'm mixing up containing the trivial representation with containing a $0$-weight space. Thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: The other key point is that if you don't contain the trivial and you do contain a self-dual irrep, then the answer is 2.  This actually covers most cases.  All that's left is $SU(n)$, reps of $SO(4n+2)$ whose highest weights are multiples of the spin weight, and some reps of $E_6$.  I don't see a particularly easy way to handle $SU(n)$ other than just using central character, and somehow checking you don't get very very unlucky and miss the trivial in the smallest non-trivial multiple landing in the root lattice.

Comment: @NoahSnyder In what sense "this actually covers most cases"?

Comment: A really good exercise is to see that taking duals of irreps of a Lie algebra is always implemented by an order 2 Dynkin diagram automorphism.  So if your Dynkin diagram doesn't have an involution then every rep is self-dual.  Even when it does have an involution it still might be that every rep is self-dual (this happens the even type D's) or it might be that most of the vertices are fixed (happens for the odd type D's).  The cases I listed are the only actual non-self-dual irreps.

Comment: @NoahSnyder: This does not sound right: If the opposition involution $\iota=-w_0$ is not the identity map then there are always dominant weights which are not fixed by $\iota$, hence, the corresponding irreps are not self-dual.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: the point is, when $-w_0$ is not the identity, it is (or "comes from") an order two Dynkin diagram automorphism, like Noah said. So if your diagram lacks such an automorphism, then $-w_0$ must be the identity.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Sure, but this leaves out all "most" of highest weights of A and D (odd): It is simply not enough to consider the nodes of the Dynkin diagram.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: maybe we shouldn't drag this conversation in the comments out, but doesn't that exactly agree with what Noah's earlier comment says: $SU(n)$ and $SO(4n+2)$ need to be dealt with via some other considerations.

Comment: @SamHopkins: My objection was to the claim that  "All that's left is ... reps of (4+2)  highest weights are multiples of the spin weight." But, I agree, there is no point.

Comment: Moishe’s right that my list was too restrictive in the type D odd case.  That case is also going to be trickier like the SU(n) case, except that now I think you’re only looking at like 4th powers (or maybe just 2nd? what’s the center?) so it should be easier.